# Factor sympy expression to matrix coefficients?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I have tried to be diligent in looking through documentation and am coming up empty.

I am trying to factor or eliminate terms in a expression to matrix form.  My problem appears to differ from polynomial factoring (as I plan to implement a function `phi(x,y,z) = a_1 + a_2*x + a_3*y + a_4*z`)

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, pprint
from sympy.solvers import solve

phi_1, phi_2, x, a_1, a_2, L = symbols("phi_1, phi_2, x, a_1, a_2, L")

#Linear Interpolation function: phi(x)
phi = a_1 + a_2*x
#Solve for coefficients (a_1, a_2) with BC's: phi(x) @ x=0, x=L
shape_coeffs = solve([Eq(phi_1, phi).subs({x:0}), Eq(phi_2, phi).subs({x:L})], (a_1, a_2))
pprint(shape_coeffs)
#Substitute known coefficients
phi = phi.subs(shape_coeffs)
pprint(phi)
```

This works as expected, however, I would like to factor this to matrix form, where :

[image: Current and Desired]

I have tried `factor()`, `cancel()`, `as_coefficient()` with no success.  On paper, this is a trivial problem.  What am I missing in the sympy solution?  Thanks.

### A valid method: Taken as the answer

```
C_1, C_2 = symbols("C_1, C_2", cls=Wild)
N = Matrix(1,2, [C_1, C_2])
N = N.subs(phi.match(C_1*phi_1 + C_2*phi_2))
phi_i = Matrix([phi_1, phi_2])
display(Math("\phi(x)_{answered} = " + latex(N) + "\ * " + latex(phi_i)))
```

[image: Correct Answer Output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[My first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30113995/1) used `phi.match(form)` to find the coefficients, but that doesn't seem to work so well [when matching many Wild symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209215/sympy-collect-symbols-for-matrix-coefficients%3E). So instead, I think a better approach is to use `phi = collect(expand(...))` and then use `phi.coeff` to find the coefficients:

```
import sympy as sy

phi_1, phi_2, x, a_1, a_2, L = sy.symbols("phi_1, phi_2, x, a_1, a_2, L")

phi = a_1 + a_2*x
shape_coeffs = sy.solve([sy.Eq(phi_1, phi).subs({x:0}), sy.Eq(phi_2, phi).subs({x:L})], (a_1, a_2))
phi = phi.subs(shape_coeffs)

phi = sy.collect(sy.expand(phi), phi_1)
N = sy.Matrix([phi.coeff(v) for v in (phi_1, phi_2)]).transpose()
print(N)
```

yields

```
Matrix([[1 - x/L, x/L]])
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but in trying to implement the solution with more Wilds and Symbols, match returns None.  I have posted a new question because I was uncertain about 'SO' conventions: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209215/sympy-collect-symbols-for-matrix-coefficients>

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the previous answer in this post. The function here takes a vector (`sympy.Matrix`) as input and the corresponding coefficients also represented as a vector (`sympy.Matrix`) to factorize and extract the matrix A, such that `vec = A @ coeffs`.

```py
import sympy as sp 

def factorize_vec(vec:sp.Matrix, coeffs:sp.Matrix):
    '''
    Factorize a vector into the product of a matrix and its coefficients. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    - `vec` : column vector of equations
    - `coeffs` : column vector of coefficients to factorize 

    Return
    ------
    - `A` : vec = A@coeffs
    '''
    A = sp.zeros(len(vec),len(coeffs))
    for i,v in enumerate(vec):
        expr = sp.collect(sp.expand(v), syms=coeffs[:])
        for j,c in enumerate(coeffs):
            A[i,j] = expr.coeff(coeffs[j]) 
    return A
```