# sympy: Collect symbols for matrix coefficients?

Tags: matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomial-math

#### I am trying to factor an expression, and separate coefficients to matrix form, such that:

[image: Generic]

Closely related to [Factor sympy expression to matrix coefficients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112645/factor-sympy-expression-to-matrix-coefficients), where Wild symbols are used with `match(form)` to determine coefficients for its matrix form. However, I am unable to get the `match(form)` method to work for the following.

> **Why does `match(form)` method fail?**
>
> **What are clean alternatives to accomplish this?**

```py
#Linear Interpolation function: V(x)
v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2, x, L = symbols("v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2, x, L")
a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = symbols("a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4", real=True)
V = a_1*x**0 + a_2*x**1 + a_3*x**2 + a_4*x**3
#Solve for coefficients (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) with BC's: V(x) @ x=0, x=L
shape_coeffs = solve([Eq(v_1, V.subs({x:0})), 
                      Eq(theta_1, V.diff(x).subs({x:0})), 
                      Eq(v_2, V.subs({x:L})), 
                      Eq(theta_2, V.diff(x).subs({x:L}))], 
                     (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4))
V = V.subs(shape_coeffs)
#Factor to matrix
V = sympy.collect(sympy.expand(V), (v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2))
```

[image: Setup]

And collect terms until the matrix form is apparent.  To match forms:

```py
C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4 = symbols("C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4", cls=Wild)
form = c_1*v_1 + c_2*theta_1 + c_3*v_2 + c_4*theta_2
mat_coeffs = V.match(form)
N = Matrix([C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4]).transpose()
N = N.subs(mat_coeffs)
v = Matrix([v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2])
```

[image: Desired]

Unlike the referenced question, `V.match(form)`, returns **None** instead of a **dict()** containing `{C_1:f(x), C_2:f(x), C_3:f(x), C_4:f(x)}`.  Why does this fail? -- by inspection, the solution is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `collect(expand(V), ...)` already shows `V` as a linear polynomial in the variables `v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2`, instead of using `V.match(form)`, perhaps an easier, more direct way to get the coefficients is to use the `V.coeff` method:

```py
N = sy.Matrix([V.coeff(v) for v in (v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2)]).transpose()
```

---

```py
import sympy as sy
#Linear Interpolation function: V(x)
v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2, x, L = sy.symbols(
    "v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2, x, L")
a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = sy.symbols("a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4", real=True)
V = a_1*x**0 + a_2*x**1 + a_3*x**2 + a_4*x**3
#Solve for coefficients (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) with BC's: V(x) @ x=0, x=L
shape_coeffs = sy.solve([sy.Eq(v_1, V.subs({x:0})), 
                      sy.Eq(theta_1, V.diff(x).subs({x:0})), 
                      sy.Eq(v_2, V.subs({x:L})), 
                      sy.Eq(theta_2, V.diff(x).subs({x:L}))], 
                     (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4))
V = V.subs(shape_coeffs)
V = sy.collect(sy.expand(V), (v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2))
N = sy.Matrix([V.coeff(v) for v in (v_1, theta_1, v_2, theta_2)]).transpose()
print(N)
```

yields

```py
Matrix([[1 - 3*x**2/L**2 + 2*x**3/L**3, x - 2*x**2/L + x**3/L**2, 3*x**2/L**2 - 2*x**3/L**3, -x**2/L + x**3/L**2]])
```

Comment: Excellent solution: I had a method using `.coeff()` but it was a little messy without your list comprehension.  `.coeff()` seems to be the most stable for all cases.  Still, any guesses why the `.match(form)` fails?  Any advantage to either method?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not well versed in how `.match(form)` is implemented.  Finding the
coefficients of a polynomial has a deterministic (guaranteed-to-succeed)
algorithm.  Pattern-matching is a more open-ended problem. So if a problem
avails itself to both approaches -- as long as `V` can be expressed as a
polynomial in the `v` and `theta` variables -- I would definitely choose to use
`.coeff()`.